# Minimizing DB queries in cases where the resource is browser cached (Django project)

Tags: django, browser-cache

In a Django web application I'm developing, there's a page where I need to display multiple user avatars in a list. In the relevant view, I employ the Django ORM to fetch these urls like so:

```
Avatar.objects.filter(id__in=user_list).values('id','url)
```

Next, I've set up my nginx webserver to cache static resources, simply via:

```
map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch;
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    ~image/                    max;
}
```

My understanding is, whenever the view servicing the avatars list page is processed, the earlier Django ORM query would always be run. Thus, the webserver caching allows me to save GET requests, but *not the actual database look up*. Is this understanding correct?

If so, what's the pattern for calling ORM queries only if the images are not cached in the browser? Is that possible (or advisable) at all? And if not, why not?

I'm interested in understanding the best practices of web development in cases such as these. Illustrative examples would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you'll probably want to keep things as they are and query the DB each time (and there's nothing bad about that!)

The browser needs to get a URL for each image in order to check if it's in its cache, and the URL ultimately comes from the DB. You can get around this by caching the results of the query on the server side if you must, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you have performance issues. This cache would be completely independent of (and have no awareness of) the browser cache.

Below are the steps that are more-or-less my mental model of this problem - hope this is helpful:

1. Browser - sends request to Webserver
2. Weberver - gets request, queries DB for image URL
3. DB - replies to Webserver
4. Webserver - replies to Browser with a webpage
5. Browser - inspects response for other resources (e.g. img tags with URLs)
6. Browser - Checks its cache for these resources and displays them if they are cached and valid
7. Browser - Requests resources it doesn't have cached from Imageserver
8. Imageserver - Delivers image content to Browser, including caching headers
9. Browser - Displays the image

Notes:

Webserver and Imageserver can be the same or different. The caching headers that Imageserver sends are the ones that matter to get the Browser to cache them.

You mentioned you set up NGINX to cache the static resources. It's not caching, but sending headers that contain instructions about caching to the browser requesting the resource.